# how to display iphone addressbook in indexed table view

Tags: iphone, addressbook

i am writing an iphone application where i am accessing contacts from AddressBook. I've successfully displayed the contacts using ABPeoplePickerNavigationController. Now now i want to do is to display contacts in alphabetically separate sections, and with alphabetic index on right side just like in [this imag](http://www.isoaxis.com/temp/peoplePicker.png)e. http://www.isoaxis.com/temp/peoplePicker.png

How should i do that???
Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe ABPeoplePickerNavigationController has this alphabet index by default. You probably just don't have enough contacts in the phonebook.
Have you tried to increase number of contacts?

Comment: yeah thank u for the tip... i jst got it by adding more contacts
thank u,
Cheers